# configparser stopped working and ConfigParser is OK! on Python 2.7

Tags: configparser

I have been using my computer, 
running experiments with Python 2.7 and `configparser` worked fine!

Today it decided to stop working 
and I changed `configparser` to `ConfigParser`, and
it worked! Still on Python 2.7.

Any idea how to revert that? Make it work again with `configparser`?

I do not want to go through all my code
and change them. On top of that it is irritating that
all of a sudden it decided to stop working!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import the module under a different name:

```
import ConfigParser as configparser
```

This change was introduced in Python 3.0 back in 2007, it is documented in the ["What's New In Python 3.0"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Doc/whatsnew/3.0.rst#library-changes) as well as the [PEP 3108 document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#pep-8-violations-done) in section "PEP 8 violations". A few modules, including `ConfigParser`, were renamed to comply with Python's PEP8 style guide. Quote:

> PEP 8 specifies that modules "should have short, all-lowercase names" where "underscores can be used ... if it improves readability".

Comment: I know! it was just weird and annoying.
I was wondering why, if anyone knows why that has happened.
Thanks.

Comment: @JoseLight I did some digging in the Python history and documents, I edited my post and added the findings